# How get attributes of a domText object? (Which is really a span element)

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I don't know exactly why, but my span element is a DomText object. And I couldn't get the attribute of the span.

I use the simple DomDocument (instead of xpath) because of this is more faster than other solutions, which I tried.

```
    $dom = new \DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($contentOfDom);

    $trs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

    $result = array();

    $previous = null;
    foreach ($trs as $tr) {
          $current = null;

          foreach ($tr->childNodes as $td) {

                if ($td->nodeName === 'td') {                        
                    $current[] = trim($td->nodeValue);
                    $childOfTD = $td->childNodes->item(0);
                    print_r($childOfTD);
                    //echo 'title:'.$childOfTD->getAttribute('title')."<br>";
                    //var_dump($childOfTD->getAttribute('name') == "title");
                }
         } 
        //.... other codes
}
```

This is the TD which has a span element:

```
<td>
    <span class="emphasize" title="this modified">
    2.36
    </span>
</td>
```

The `$td->nodeValue` will get the 2.36 value, this is good. But I don't get the span's title attribute, because I need check that.
(However, maybe I can check it before the value will be updated into the database - maybe this is faster)

And this is how look that `nodevalue` (alias the `print_r($element)`)

```
 DOMText Object ( 
     [wholeText] => 2.36
     [data] => 2.36
     [length] => 25
     [nodeName] => #text
     [nodeValue] => 2.36
     [nodeType] => 3
     [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
     [childNodes] => 
     [firstChild] => 
     [lastChild] => 
     [previousSibling] =>
     [attributes] =>
     [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted) 
     [namespaceURI] => 
     [prefix] => 
     [localName] => 
     [baseURI] => 
     [textContent] => 2.36
     )
```

Somehow I would like to get the span's title attribute with domdocument. However if this is not possible then I am open minded on every fast solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your span element is not a DomText object.

The *spaces* between the `td` start tag and the `span` start tag are the DomText object.

```
<td>
    <span class="emphasize" title="this modified">
```

Loop over the child nodes until you find the span, or use [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getelementsbytagname.php) instead of `childNodes`.

Comment: I tried but nothing, I got an span from an other TD, which is a DomObject, but I don't get the span of the DomText... :(

Comment: Okay, the span is not a DomText, but how can I get from the TD? With loop is find only in one other span...
I got this error: `Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute()`

Comment: The span element is not a child of the text between the start of the `td` and the start of the `span`, it is a chid element of the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
if ($td->nodeName === 'td') {                        
       $current[] = trim($td->nodeValue);
       $childOfTD = $td->childNodes->item(0);
       // print_r($childOfTD);
       // ====================== title ==================
       $title = $td->getElementsByTagName("span")->item(0)->getAttribute("title");
       echo $title;
       // ===============================================
}
```

Comment: I tried but it can't finds the span element in a DomText still... only just in a DomObject... :( Yeap, I modified the `item(0)` to 1 or above, but it doesn't work with DomText... 
It seems the `getElementsByTagnName` doesn't work in DomText: `Call to undefined method DOMText::getAttribute()`